# iPhone Drawing in Browser

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Can I develop an application on web to draw something on iPhone? I guess not because when I draw in the browser it will be treated as "dragging" but I just want to double check for a solution out there.

Thanks.
Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean to ask if is possible to draw into a `UIWebView`?

I don't think so. In `UIWebView` the page display view is embedded in a scroll view and scroll views trap all touches to determine if they can scroll. It's pretty much configured as read only.

You could in theory put a transparent view over the web view to trap the touches then send those to the the actual browser view. I haven't done it but it might possible.